# How to reject a recursive promise and redirect to login page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a recursive Promise to fetch the data from the server ( The server response is paginate).

**My wish is when the response is not 200/1 to reject the promise and to redirect to the login page. How should i do it?**

In the commented code line inside the `catch`, the client continue to fetch the server endlessly and never move to the login page

thank you in advance,
Below is my code

```
// inside some function
useEffect(() => {
          const token = some token
          let url = "someurl"
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            getData(url, token, [], resolve, reject)
          })
            .then(response => {
                console.log("do something")
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                *****here i want to show an alert box and redirect the user to the login page*** 
                // alert("Something went wrong", err);
                // <Redirect to='/login' />
                //props.history.push('/login')

            })
}, [])

const getData = (url, token, tests, resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            },
        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status !== 200) {
                reject(new Error('bad request'));
            }
            else{
                return res.json();
            }

        })
        .then(json => {
            getData(json.next, token, retrived, resolve, reject) 
        })
    }
```

Comment: Whats the problem in your current implementation? I mean if you put the alert in that catch block and then redirect user to login page?

Comment: it dosenot work, it is continue fetching the sever in an endless loop

Comment: Can you share the full code? or create a minimal example of your code?

Comment: I added , the promise is inside useEffect